# didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL is not getting called and warning for 'self'

Tags: macos, avfoundation

I created a small program with AVFoundation which was working as intended - recording screen. I couldn't work on it some time due to my studies and finally, when I tried to run the program in the latest OS (Mountain Lion) with Xcode 4, the delegate '`didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL`' is not getting called. Further I'm receiving a warning:
[image: Code Showing the warning]

I'm a novice in Cocoa. However, this warning is confusing as previously I had no such problem...
I would very much appreciate for any help in this regard...

Comment: Sure that `mMovieFileOutput` is not `nil`? (Btw ignore the warning...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the delegate protocol in your interface declaration for AppDelegate, eg

`@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate>`